# Order of focusing on and learning different skills

Tags: photorealism

I've been using blender for a short while. I can handle different aspects of a project without encountering *beginnery* problems, but there's still a lot to learn about various skills: **modeling, rigging. animating, materials, sculpting, Geometry nodes, lightning, compositing** and other things I might not be familiar with.

Following the advice of Blender Guru, I'm aiming for photorealism. So, in what order should I start learning the skills that I mentioned?(plus missed skills)

I know I should learn them simultaneously and along the way, but in which order I should try to focus on a specific skill for like two weeks?

Comment: Sorry it is opinion based Q ... in general it doesnt make a sence to learn lightning if you dont have a model to light, on other hand you can download some model and only work on lightning process to finish your project. I don't think there is an answer for you.

Comment: Voted to close, opinion based.  My opinion: doesn't matter, provided you have decent stuff to work on (downloaded models if you want to delay modelling, for example; you need good animation topo to learn rigging et al, which you won't have if you haven't worked on modelling yet-- but it's back and forth, you won't know good animation topo until you do a bit of rigging.)  A good artist does *not* master all domains; a good artist learns the basics of all domains and then specializes in one domain.  If you want to learn "photorealism" I'd say work on materials.

Comment: Admire your dedication @Barbod. After two years I'm only somewhat profficient at modeling, all the other areas are alien to me :D. Perhaps I should step up my game.

Comment: The answer is: Create something with the skills you have now.  Decide what you would like to improve about it.  Work on those skills next. Iterate.  For photorealism, you might want to work on modeling, materials, and lighting, all of which are relevant and can be studied independently.

Comment: What you want to learn sounds like this video clip [Pet tortoise thinks it's a dog](https://youtu.be/Mqm1DOW6CJs). It's made with Blender.
A good starting point to learn is to recreate a picture in 3D. For animation, try the [Dynamic Machines Challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0-IkxXyhmY) or maybe create a [Puzzle Machine](https://youtu.be/RnNdyCbwzn0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of question always gets closed as opinion based, but as usual, there's a factual answer:

The list you've provided are pretty much independent of each other, so if you have the basics, there is no necessary order.

So how do you decide if that's the case?  The same way artists always decide:  Create something.  Decide what you most want to improve about it.  Work on those skills next.

You mentioned photorealism.  There are three skills to work on there, modeling, materials, and lighting.  Create a scene. Study it. Decide what to improve. Work on that.

Comment: Despite it being closed, I got my answer . The answer might sound obvious but it wasn't for me. Thank you. Also thanks to @Blunder and everyone else.